# contentOffset doesn't change from 0

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4

Pretty much I need to detect when the scrollView is at 320 x to execute some code but the contentOffset seems to always be 0. When i set `position==0` the code executes but i need it to execute at 320. Any ideas?

```
(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIView *)sender
{
    int position = (_scrollView.contentOffset.x);
    if(position==320)
    {
    // Code Here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the sender parameter rather than whatever variable _scrollView referes to (which may not be hooked up correctly)

Also, don't cast the contentOffset.x to an int, it's really a CGFloat

```
(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)sender
{
    if(sender.contentOffset.x==320)
    {
    // Code Here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is called after the scroll view has come to a stop (after decelerating and bouncing, etc.), so if your scroll view is 320 wide and its `contentSize.width` is also 320 (or less, I think) then that would explain why it always comes to a stop at 0. Assuming that the scroll view width is 320, if you set the `contentSize.width` to 640 then when you scroll all the way to the right hand side (dragging the content to the left) then the `contentOffset.x` should be 320 when it comes to rest.

```
+--------------+ <- Scroll View, 320 wide.
|              |
|+-------------------------------+ <- contentSize.width is 640
||                               |
||                               |
||                               |
|+-------------------------------+
|              |
+--------------+
 ^ contentOffset.x is 0

                  +--------------+ <- Scroll View, 320 wide.
                  |              |
+-------------------------------+| <- contentSize.width is 640
|                               ||
|                               ||
|                               ||
+-------------------------------+|
                  |              |
                  +--------------+
                  ^ contentOffset.x is 320
```

As you can see from the diagram above, the content offset is the point inside the content view that aligns with the origin of the scroll view.